# How to show whole content of an Xml file in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlreader, xmlwriter

i need to display whole content of an xml file in a textbox,so a user can see it and change it,and then i have to update the xml file.The user knows xml and how it works,i just need to display whole content of an xml file in a textbox on the page and after button clicking ,update the file,can anyone help me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load:

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

To save:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Hey,thank you so much,i can read the file but WriteAllText method doesnt work :S

Comment: i just tested it and it doesnt re-write on the file.I've created a blank txt file it has worked,but the function doesnt re-write the content

Comment: So when you call WriteAllText, does it do nothing, does it throw an exception, or does it blank the file out?  If it simply does nothing, do you happen to have it in a try/catch block that is eating an exception so you don't see the exception?

Comment: im sorry,i have just forgotten to add !IsPostBack line . Thank you for your answer,it works great :)